# How to reset key binding settings in sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Be a freshman to Sublime Text 2, I changed hotkeys in "key binding - default", now I know I should use "key binding - user", but the question is how do I restore the default key settings manually? I need to run a compare on default settings so that leave only changed lines to user key settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed a `Default` file in Sublime and saved it, you'll need to reinstall Sublime in order to get the original back - this is exactly why you shouldn't do that. I'd strongly recommend upgrading to [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3), as it has *many* new features and bug fixes over ST2 (which is not being developed at all now), and has been rock-stable for probably 2 years or more. In addition to all sorts of other benefits, ST3 does not allow you to edit `Default` files.